# Can I display heading below its tabs?

Tags: navigation, consistency

Look at the navigation. In the upper  mockup I have User's profile with a few tabs and there's no header, just the information about the user below (something like here on UX Stack Exchange). Also I am not showing the avatar within other tabs in User's profile, so the content is different every time, just the tabs stay. In the bottom mockup I have a particular game page, also with tabs, but with a header this time to inform users which game they are dealing with now (and this time the header is placed within its every tab)/

There's also indication of both "categories" in the sidebar.

And I am struggling with a dilemma.

- On one hand, I would like to put the "Game name 1" header above the tabs, so the hierarchy is shown - after all those tabs refer to this game.
- On the other hand though, I would really like to keep it consistent, meaning the tabs would stay in the same place, no matter the page. (and this is the solution I am leaning towards, as shown in the mockups)

What do I do? Is the second **solution** mentioned above (not the mockup) wrong?

[[image]

[image]

Comment: Having just seen your other question about breadcrumbs, I would definitely consider moving the game-name/user-name into the "title bar" as with tabs, title and breadcrumbs, there's less-and-less space available for the "real" page.

Answer (score 4):

You ought to maintain consistency and hierarchy.

The heading should always come first otherwise the tabs make little sense. Also, all pages should have a heading (for accessibility reasons).

Why not just use the users name as the heading for the user page and the game name for the game pages? That way you'll have the correct information hierarchy as well as consistency between pages with the heading and the tabs always being in the same place?

Comment: @Ola Depending on the size of "App Name" you could perhaps use the space to the right of that (just past the right of the sidebar divider) for the user or game name header.

Comment: I think that area conceptually in app related rather than content related, so that might be confusing, I'd just go for a heading at the top of the content area

Comment: @ToniLeigh, I don't feel the idea of putting user name above the tabs, bc I feel it should be near the avatar and it's pretty big, so the tabs would go way down and thus be in different positions than on other pages anyway so still no consistency. Or without the avatar there would be the name alone, then tabs then the avatar which would take up even more space. Btw in another question I got the answer that I do not need headers on every page if other indications are prominent enough, so which advice should I really follow? (And what do you think about tabs here on UXSE? They're above headers)

Comment: @OlaOsinska On this site the tabs are related to site wide content, but the title is for the question (page content) but in your example the tabs are related to the page content

Comment: @ToniLeigh, No, I mean the tabs related to the user, not the general site content. When you want to explore your profile or someone else's you have Profile and Activity tabs  (and Settings if it's yours). And then below your have the content, the profile picture, name, badges and questions and answers that this person wrote.